# using regular expressions isolate the words with ei or ie in it

Tags: python-3.x

How do I use regular expressions isolate the words with ei or ie in it?

```
import re
value = ("How can one receive one who over achieves while believing that he/she cannot be deceived.")
list = re.findall("[ei,ie]\w+", value)
print(list)
```

it should print `['receive', 'achieves', 'believing', 'deceived']`, but I get `['eceive', 'er', 'ieves', 'ile', 'elieving', 'eceived']` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set syntax  `[]` is for individual characters, so use `(?:)` instead, with words separated by `|`. This is like using a group, but it doesn't capture a match group like `()` would. You also want the `\w` on either side to be captured to get the whole word.

```
import re
value = ("How can one receive one who over achieves while believing that he/she cannot be deceived.")
list = re.findall("(\w*(?:ei|ie)\w*)", value)
print(list)
```

---

```
['receive', 'achieves', 'believing', 'deceived']
```

(I'm assuming you meant "achieves", not "achieve" since that's the word that actually appears here.)

Comment: @abandonedarch welcome to stackoverflow. If the answer meets your needs, accept it with the check mark.